# Изменение значения при выборе двух списков (select)

Tags: php, javascript, select

Есть два списка `select` зависящие друг от друга, то есть при выборе в первом списке выводятся разные данные второго списка. При этом от выбора в обоих списков меняется еще одно значение (например цена).

Все работает кроме одного нюанса, опишу ход действий:

1. В первом и во втором списках по умолчанию выведено первое значение по списку и **третие значение** (цена) отображается.
2. Выбираю **во втором списке**, другое значение, **цена** пропадает и новая не появляется
3. Выбираю в **первом списке** любой другой пункт, во втором списке цены у всех значений появляются,
4. Возвращаю **в первом списке** первый вариант, после **во втором списке** все цены **появляются** у всех значений.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var sel = document.getElementById("customfields");
 
 var SizePrice = 0;
 if(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex] != undefined) {
  SizePrice = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
 }
 
 $('#customfield').val(SizePrice);
 var sel1 = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
 var ptype= sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].text;
 $('#ptype').val(ptype);
 
  $('#dropdown1').change(function() {  
   var Type=$('#dropdown1').val();
   var sel1 = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
   var ptype= sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].text;
   $('#ptype').val(ptype);
   //alert("herer"+type1);
   var URL='ajax.php';
   $.ajax({  //ajax call
    type: "GET",     
    url: "ajax.php", 
    data: "Type="+Type
    }).done(function(msg) { 
     //alert("in def=="+msg);
     $("#customfields").html(msg); 
     var sel = document.getElementById("customfields");
     var SizePrice= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
     //alert("SizePrice=="+SizePrice);
     var ExplodePrice=SizePrice.split("Rs.");
     
     ExplodePrice[1] = $(sel).find(':selected').data('price');
     
     //alert("expl=="+ExplodePrice[1]);
     $('#product_price').val(ExplodePrice[1]);
     $('#product_price2').val(ExplodePrice[1]);
     $('#actualprice').html(ExplodePrice[1]);
     $('#customfield').val(SizePrice);
    });
  });
  $('#customfields').change(function() { 
   //alert("here");
   //var SizePrice=$('#customfields').text();
   var sel = document.getElementById("customfields");
   var SizePrice= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
   //alert("SizePrice=="+SizePrice);
   var ExplodePrice=SizePrice.split("Rs.");
   
   ExplodePrice[1] = $(sel).find(':selected').data('price');
   
   //alert("expl=="+ExplodePrice[1]);
   $('#product_price').val(ExplodePrice[1]);
   $('#product_price2').val(ExplodePrice[1]);
   $('#actualprice').html(ExplodePrice[1]);
   $('#customfield').val(SizePrice);
   //alert(sel1);
  });
 });
```

```html
<?php
$Type= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['Type']);

if ($Type!=""){
 $fetch = "SELECT id,Description,Price FROM vak16_customfields where Customid=".$Type;
 //echo "in if".$fetch;
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$fetch) or die(mysqli_error());
 if($result){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
   $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
   $row_array['value'] = $row['Description'];
   $row_array['price'] = $row['Price'];
   array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
  }
 }
}
?>

<?php echo $product_price; ?>" /> 

<select class="form-control" name="select" id="dropdown1" placeholder="Type" >
  <?php $GetTypeDetails=GetTypeDetails();        
    for($k=0;$k<sizeof($GetTypeDetails);$k++){ 
  ?>       
<option value="<?php echo $GetTypeDetails[$k]['id']; ?>">
      <?php echo $GetTypeDetails[$k]['CustomTitle']; ?></option>        
   <?php }?>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="customfields" name="select" placeholder="Size" >
 <?php
  $GetSizeDetails=GetSizeDetails();
  for($k=0;$k<sizeof($GetSizeDetails);$k++){ 
 ?>       
<option value="<?php echo $GetSizeDetails[$k]['id']; ?>">
  <?php echo $GetSizeDetails[$k]['Description']; ?>
</option>        
 <?php  }?>
</select>
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Написал для вас рабочий пример пример:

```
<?php

$arr1 = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 0,
        'name' => 'One'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Two'
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Three'
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Four'
    ],
];

$arr2 = [
    0 => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 0,
            'name' => 'One.One',
            'price' => 1100
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'One.Two',
            'price' => 1600
        ],
        2 => [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'One.Three',
            'price' => 800
        ],
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Two.One',
            'price' => 990
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'Two.Two',
            'price' => 2200
        ],
    ],
    2 => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Three.One',
            'price' => 3500
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 6,
            'name' => 'Three.Two',
            'price' => 2900
        ],
        2 => [
            'id' => 7,
            'name' => 'Three.Three',
            'price' => 1800
        ],
        3 => [
            'id' => 8,
            'name' => 'Three.Three',
            'price' => 960
        ],
    ],
];

if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'products' => ((isset($arr2[$_POST['category']])) ? $arr2[$_POST['category']] : [])]);
    exit();
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            body > div {
                width: 300px;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 20px auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Price <span data-id='price'>-</span> rub.
            </p>
            <p>
                Category
                <select data-id='categories'>
                    <option value="">- Select category -</option>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value['id'];?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                Product
                <select data-id='products'>
                    <option value="">- Select category -</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-id="categories"]').change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "?ajax",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: ({
                                category: $(this).val()
                            }),
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(result){
                                if (!result.success) {
                                    alert('bad');
                                    return;
                                }
                                $('[data-id="products"]').html( 
                                    (result.products.length > 0) ? 
                                    result.products.map(function(product){
                                        return '<option value="'+product.id+'" data-price="'+product.price+'">'+product.name+'</option>'
                                    }) : '<option value="">- no products -</option>'
                                );
                                calcPrice();
                            }
                        });
                });

                $('[data-id="products"]').change(function(){
                    calcPrice();
                });

                calcPrice();
            });

            function calcPrice() {
                var priceBlock = $('[data-id="price"]');
                priceBlock.html( $('[data-id="products"] > option:selected').attr('data-price') || 0 );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо что написали новый рабочий код, но мне бы исправить мой ? :)

Comment: предлагаю подключить голову и исправить свой, используя мой рабочий вариант.

Comment: уже 2 часа пытаюсь, что то ни как :(